# Create one row with values from table with data in diagonal only

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, null, append

I have the following table in pandas-

```
>>>index1   index2   index3   index4   index5   index6   index7
0   sig      null    null     null     null     null     null
1   null      sig     null     null     null     null     null
2   null      null    sig      null     null     null     null
3   null      null    null     sig      null     null     null
4   null      null    null     null     no sig   null     null
5   null      null    null     null     null     no sig   null
6   null      null    null     null     null     null     sig
```

I would like to get rid of the reduce the null values and to have the data in one row like this:

```
>>>index1   index2   index3   index4   index5   index6   index7
0   sig      sig     sig      sig      no sig   no sig   sig
```

It's important to say that I get the first table with the null data by if statemnt; I have calculated statistic test for each index and based on the p value, I give each index value of sig or no sig, using append:

```
for i in indices:
    stat, p = friedmanchisquare(df[1][i],df[2][i],df[3][i],df[4][i],df[5][i])
    #print(i,p)
    if p<0.05:
        friedman=friedman.append({i:'sig'},ignore_index=True)
    else:
        friedman=friedman.append({i:'no sig'},ignore_index=True)
```

So I believe that the append creates the big table with the many null values.

**My end goal: to get the one row table, either in the of loop stage (e.g to use something else than append?) or to "fix" the big table after to get the one row**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try `np.diagonal` which return `diagonal` elemnts:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([np.diagonal(df)], columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
  index1 index2 index3 index4  index5  index6 index7
0    sig    sig    sig    sig  no sig  no sig    sig
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, use `pandas.DataFrame.bfill`:

```
new_df = df.bfill().head(1)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  index1 index2 index3 index4  index5  index6 index7
0    sig    sig    sig    sig  no sig  no sig    sig
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative with `stack` , and `droplevel`;

```
df.stack().droplevel(0).to_frame().T
```

---

```
  index1 index2 index3 index4  index5  index6 index7
0    sig    sig    sig    sig  no sig  no sig    sig
```

Answer (score 3):

A pandas solution of `np.diagonal` is `df.lookup`

```
df_diag = pd.DataFrame([df.lookup(df.index, df.columns)], columns=df.columns)

Out[47]:
  index1 index2 index3 index4  index5  index6 index7
0    sig    sig    sig    sig  no-sig  no-sig    sig
```